# Unable to set browser to default fonts

Tags: browser, fonts, control-panel

My fonts in all browser have just somehow gone wrong for no specified reason, I have tried to reset fonts setting in control panel but I didn't help, from what it looks like the font are using some new type face don't know which one, which really hard to read (see screen shot attached)..

Kindly help me how can I switch all my browsers back to the default fonts usage.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Try re-installing your fonts this way: Drag all the fonts in `Start > Control Panel > Fonts` to your desktop, drag them back to the `Fonts` window, and check if it fixed your problem.

Comment: nop, problem is still there as same..